# Porting/Migrating Windows Phone 8.1 Project to Windows 10 UWP Projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone-8.1, uwp

I have an existing WP8.1 project. This project is incomplete and I want to port it to UWP project because I am working with Visual Studio 2017 which does not support Windows Phone apps.

How can I migrate my existing WP8.1 app to UWP?

Comment: Of course its *possible*, but that can't be your real question? You can always just rewrite the relevant code for your new platform...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some articles about migrating apps to UWP on MSDN and Windows Dev Center:

[Move from Windows Runtime 8.x to UWP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/w8x-to-uwp-root)

[Migrate apps to the Universal Windows Platform (UWP)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt148501.aspx)